# How to solve the cubic $x^3-3x+1=0$?

Tags: trigonometry, roots, cubics

This was a multiple choice question with options being
$$(A)-\cos\frac{2\pi}{9},\cos\frac{8\pi}{9},\cos\frac{14\pi}{9} \\ 
  (B)-2\cos\frac{2\pi}{9},2\cos\frac{8\pi}{9},2\cos\frac{14\pi}{9}  \\ 
  (C)-\cos\frac{2\pi}{11},\cos\frac{8\pi}{11},\cos\frac{14\pi}{11} \\ 
  (D)-2\cos\frac{2\pi}{11},2\cos\frac{8\pi}{11},2\cos\frac{14\pi}{11}$$

I tried to eliminate options using the sum and product of roots but I can't figure out if $$\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}+\cos\frac{8\pi}{9}+\cos\frac{14\pi}{9}=0$$
or 
$$\cos\frac{2\pi}{11}+\cos\frac{8\pi}{11}+\cos\frac{14\pi}{11}=0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $(2\cos \theta)^3-3(2\cos\theta)+1=2\cos3\theta+1$

Answer (score 1):

Put $x=2t$

Hence $$8t^3-6t+1=0$$ 
Now put $t=\cos \theta$
Hence $$2\cos (3\theta)=-1$$
And the rest is simple trigonometric equation

Answer (score 1):

To follow on from your method, $\cos(a) + \cos(b) = 2 \cos({a+b\over2}) \cos({a-b\over2})$, so $$\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}+\cos\frac{8\pi}{9}=2 \cos\frac{5\pi}{9}\cos\frac{3\pi}9=\cos\frac{5\pi}{9}$$
but $\cos\frac{5\pi}{9} = -\cos\frac{14\pi}{9}$, so the sum $\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}+\cos\frac{8\pi}{9}+\cos\frac{14\pi}{9}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=a\cos t$

Comparing with $\cos3t$ formula $$\dfrac{a^3}4=\dfrac{3a}3, a=?$$

$$a\cos3t=-1$$

$$3t:360^\circ n\pm120^\circ$$

Comment: Observe that the coefficient $2$ in other answers  has been determined algebrically here

Comment: Why downvote? This answer gives a general approach.

Comment: @CYAries, There are actually two of them! With the given volume of users here in MSE, I don't always expect quality feedback:)