# Using triple-angle formula to find answer to polynomial equation

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

Question: Use $\cos(3θ) = 4\cos^3(θ)-3\cos(θ)$ to find the three roots of $8x^3-6x=1.$

Currently, I have figured out that if you double the triple angle formula above you can line the two equations up to get $\cos(3θ) = 1/2$. However, I don't know where to go from here.

**Update:**

After letting x = cos(θ), I have found that θ = 20 or θ = 100 as x = 1/2. However, the question states that there are three answers. How do I find the third answer?

**Answer to updated question:**

The third answer is -0.7660 as cos(420) = 1/2.

Comment: Try: $x=\cos(\theta)$ and divide both sides by 2.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: In other words, $4x^3-3x = \frac 12$

Comment: I don't know that you need angles to solve this equation unless the part under the radicals in the general cubic formula are negative. If so, DeMoivre's Theorem may apply. Here is a link to the formula that will always work if the intermediate calculations are real.

https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/cubic/

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2739299/how-to-solve-the-cubic-x3-3x1-0/2739305#2739305

Answer (score 0):

Hint: To find all three answers of $\cos 3 \theta = 1/2$, once we solve the equation, we get $\theta = 20^\circ + 120^\circ k$ (or $\theta = \pi/9 + 2\pi k/9$ in radians), so in order to find all three values, we would have to set $k = 0, 1 \text { and } 2$.